# How to run multiple docker containers accessible by another host on same network

Tags: docker, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 machine with docker installed. The host is connected to a private LAN 192.168.0.0/24.
My container app exposes a UDP and a TCP port. I'd like to run multiple instances of the container and have them all accessible to other (non-docker) machines on the same network. I must be able to use the defined port numbers, not randomly generated ones. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody responded and I've now figured it out for myself, I'll answer my own question. Of course there may be other ways to skin this cat...

## Create a VLAN

Cribbed from https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/

- From the Start menu, open the Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager
- On the right hand side click on Virtual Switch Manager
- Create a new External network
- Give it a concise name
- select your network device from the drop down list (the device must have an active connection!)
- Reboot!

## Create nodes / machines

The containers will have a 1:1 port mapping on the host, so we will create a machine for each container we wish to run.

- Create a thin VM (just do one for now and repeat these instruction for each container as required): `docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "concise_name" My_Node_1`
- Launch a Powershell with Admin privileges
- Switch the context of the shell docker commands towards the new machine:     `docker-machine env My_Node_1`
- Copy and paste the last line of the output (without the #) to the shell and run it. It will be something like: `& "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env My_Node_1 | Invoke-Expression`
  From now on all of the `docker` commands will be executed on the machine `My_Node_1`.

## Build and run

- cd to the directory containing the Dockerfile
- Build the image, for example `docker build . -t image_name`
- Now run a container (only once per machine) using `--net=host`, for example `docker run -i -t -P -d --net=host --rm image_name`

Rinse and repeat from 'Create nodes / machines' for as many containers as required